# Search traffic significant drop since HTTPS migration

Tags: seo, https

My website has seen a dramatic drop in search engine traffic (over 50%) since swapping to https 2 months ago.

I have .htaccess rules for 301 redirects and since it is a Wordpress site, I also have a SSL plugin to change URLs on the website.

What could be causing this slump?

[image: Drop in traffic in August]

Comment: Have you also claimed and verified the https properties in Google Search Console?

Comment: Yes absolutely. 301 redirects set up via htaccess on the website too